# Is there a way to retrieve data from sub-collection inside another sub-collection?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

This is my firestore db. I want to show the list of products (i.e Image2 - document with unique ids inside "product" sub-collection) in recycler view, which I was able to do successfully. Now when I click on any item of recycler view (i.e any document of products), it navigates me to the same activity. When the activity opens up, I want to display the data inside product_id (i.e [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqLId.png) - which is inside "about" sub-collection in all documents of "product" sub-collection) on that page. How do I do it in a way - when a user clicks on particular product, that products "about" details should be displayed in the activity.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: To retrieve the data in recycler view, I directly used collectionGroup(). I don't know how to give the key as child to it for reference. Like in case of realtime database, through intent I sent the key using getAdapterPosition.getKey and in the activity I put it as a child of the database reference. So I could retrieve it further. But firestore doesn't have any feature for child, so how do I go about it?

Comment: I tried the answer by Mazhar in this post - [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799601/how-to-transfer-data-from-recyclerview-to-next-activity-when-clicked-on-cardview) to take the position and pass it as intent.

Comment: And have you solced the problem?

Comment: No, I'm unable to figure out how we can do this in firestore. How to give that position as a child to the subcollection, so that it displays the information of only the product which was clicked in recycler view list?